# Reading Config.Properties file from src/test/resources folder in MAVEN project

Tags: maven, configuration

I am new to Maven and building a project with maven and try to load config.properties file from src/test/resources folder. I tried searching solution to my problem but no success as of now. Can someone please help me in this ?

**my project structure is like this :**

```
ProjectName
--- src/test/java
       --- utilities
           ----utilities.java
                 ---getProperty()
----src/test/resources
        ----Configuration
              ---config.properties
```

---

**pom.xml includes**

```
<build>
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
       <filtering>true</filtering>
     </resource>
   </resources>

 </build>
```

---

**code to fetch config file :**

```
public class utilities()
     {
        public void getProperty()
     {
     Properties prp=new Properties();
     String propFilePath = "src/test/resources/Configuration/config.properties";
     String[] tmpArray = propFilePath.split("/");
     String propFileName=tmpArray[tmpArray.length - 1];
     ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
     InputStream inputStream = loader.getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

                if (inputStream != null)
                    {
                        prp.load(inputStream);
                    } 
     }

}
```

> Tried many options, but still getting **File Not Found Exception: property file 'config.properties' not found in the class path**
>   **NOTE:** if i am using config.properties file from src/main/resources (default location of maven). it is working fine

Please help me. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Can you confirm logged location to make sure the relative path is valid?

Comment: yes, its correct

Comment: please edit the post to show how you proved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that this file is correctly copied to the runtime classpath then it can be addressed as follows:

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream inputStream = loader.getResourceAsStream("Configuration/config.properties");
```

But ...

1. A 'test' resource will not be on the non-test runtime classpath and it's not clear whether the code you posted is run within a 'test context' or not.
2. You *seem* to be trying to load this file from `InputStream inputStream = loader.getResourceAsStream("config.properties")` rather than from `InputStream inputStream = loader.getResourceAsStream("Configuration/config.properties")`

Comment: Hi Glytching, thank you for your response. what changes i have to make in code? so that i will work. My framework needs config file to be present in src/test/resources/Configuration/Config.properties folder and my inputstream is always coming as null.

Comment: i tried using this also InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName); still no chance

Comment: The correct value for propFileName is “Configuration/config.properties” not “config.properties”. And, of course, this file must be on your runtime classpath.

Comment: can you explain runtime clasapath ?

Comment: “Runtime classpath” is the classpath used by the JVM in which your class is running.

Comment: Thanks Glytching. below code worked for me InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Configuration/config.properties");